# Dropping duplicates in SQL based on column condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table like so in SQL Server

```
ID  Type  StoreID IsPopular
101 Book  22      1
101 Book  22      0
102 Cup   67      1
102 Cup   67      0
109 Phone 88      0
```

How can I get the resulting table where I only need where IsPopular is 1 if there are duplicates for the ID?

```
ID  Type  StoreID IsPopular
101 Book  22      1
102 Cup   67      1
109 Phone 88      0
```

Comment: It's unclear *which* of these it the right choice, but both follow the same methodology.

Comment: IsPopular can be 1 or 0. If an ID has two rows each with 1 and 0, then I want to keep the one where IsPopular = 1.